# Adding extra information in Spring Rest-Docs using Attributes failing

Tags: mustache, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I'm generating documentation for APIs that are written in Python. I am using Spring Rest-Docs for this which works flawless.

Now I must add a list of roles that are authorized to call the API to each API's documentation.

What I want to do, is list with every API which roles are valid, by injecting attributes, as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#documenting-your-api-customizing-including-extra-information.

Like so:

```
@Test
public void get200_HelloWorld() throws Exception {
    this.testClient.get().uri("/hello_worlds")
        .exchange().expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectBody().consumeWith(document("{method-name}",
            requestHeaders(
                attributes(key("roles").value(
                    attributes(key("role").value("Smart User"),
                               key("role").value("Admin")))),
                    headerWithName("Accept").description("Response formats."))));
}
```

The snippet template I defined looks like:

```
Roles:
{{#roles}}
{{role}}
{{/roles}}
```

The code works and the test passes, but the documentation that is generated is not what I expected. The first `key("role").value("Smart User")` I add doesn't show. See:

```
Roles:
Admin
```

There's an error `org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.MustacheException$Context: No method or field with name 'role' on line 2` reported as well.

How can I add multiple attributes and then also print them?

I am adding the attributes to the requestHeader documentation, because that is what I will have with every API call I document.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each attribute must have a unique key. You have two attributes with the key `role`. As a result, the second `role` attribute replaces the first.

You could use a list instead:

```
attributes(key("roles").value(Arrays.asList("Smart User", "Admin")))
```

And then render each item in the list using `{{.}}`:

```
Roles:
{{#roles}}
{{.}}
{{/roles}}
```